# synchronizing access to allocated memory

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex

Is there a way to synchronize access to each element in an allocated memory. For example, if I allocate memory using the following code

```
int* counters = new int[10];
```

is there a way to synchronize modification of each counter separately (being able to modify counters[0], counters[1]...counters[9] at the same time) so that modification of, let's say, counters[0] won't block counters[9] until the lock is released to update counters[9] and the other counters while a thread is updating a specific counter, counters[0]? The counters aren't related and don't depend on any shared data with the other counters?

Comment: Use an array of mutexes. The index in the mutex array corresponds to the index in the counter array.

Comment: I thought about it but will paging the allocated memory to disk results in any data corruption. Also is there a standard way other than an array of mutexes to deal with this situation?

Comment: If paging has any visible effect on a program other than performance, it would be an incredibly serious OS bug.

Comment: You should look into atomics. If your 'counters' array is used for... counting where each array element is a counter, just make the counters atomic ints and your increase and decrease operations can have a relaxed memory ordering.

Comment: I would encapsulate the counter in a class and provide accessor methods to get/set the value, and perform the mutual exclusion inside the class. Therefore, users of the class don't even have to think about synchronization.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look into the `<atomic>` header facilities if you want to avoid using mutexes for synchronization.

Assuming your 'counters' array is simply a way to keep track of a certain number of counts, it can be done by using `std::atomic<int> counters[10]` and each counter can be incremented in a thread safe way by calling `counters[i].fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed)`.

As user Barmar has pointed out, `std::atomic<int>` could also employ a mutex internally. This is implementation dependent and can be queried by calling the `is_lock_free()` member function of a `std::atomic<int>` instance. On my implementation, `std::atomic<int>` instances are lock free.

Comment: Isn't this likely to use a mutex under the covers? So it could run into the same limit on the number of mutexes?

Comment: You are correct. I have edited my answer to make this clear.

Comment: @Barmar, while it is possible, it is certainly not LIKELY.

Comment: @SergeyA I wrongly assumed that a mutex is the most basic way to ensure atomicity.

Answer (score -2):

While array of mutexes is a natural solution, one should consider the implications. This is fine with arrays of 10 elements, but the number of mutexes is actually limited. If you have arrays of, say, 50 000 items (not that big at all) you will run out of mutexes.

Comment: What is the maximum number of mutexes allowed?

Comment: @user1886067 honestly - no idea even on my system, much less on your.

Comment: @SergeyA, what makes you say that there is a fixed limit?  POSIX does not define one, and it in fact carefully avoids asserting that must be one, other than the same general constraints of available system resources that apply everywhere.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, you can check on your system easily )

Comment: @SergeyA, as a matter of fact, I can't.  I *was* able to demonstrate that I can easily initialize 5,000,000 mutexes, lock them all, unlock them all, and then destroy them all.  I suppose I could just keep allocating and initializing mutexes until the system refuses to create any more, but I see no reason to believe that will happen before I run out of memory to store them in.